# How to get an instance of the base class in a Ruby on Rails class with inherited classes (STI)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, single-table-inheritance

I've got user and they've got pets. All kinds of pets. Reptiles, fish, birds, and mammals. The Mammal model has two sub-classes, inherited through single table inheritance (STI): cats and dogs. My user has a method to get their last pet.

In a static pages controller, I have a method to visit the user's last pet:

```
  def go_to_pet
    redirect_to current_user.last_pet || root_path
  end
```

Now the issue I'm running into is that when a cat or a dog is returned as the user's last pet, the app is looking for the cats or dogs controller, but I only have and need a mammals controller. The mammals controller is handling both cats and dogs pretty fine when it is actually invoked.

My question is such: how can I retrieve an instance of the Mammal class? I've tried Mammal.find(cat.id), but it will return a cat automatically because that's the whole point of STI.

The only ugly workaround I can think of is checking the class in the static pages controller (in the code block above) and then have redirect_to use the mammals controller, but I'd like to rather avoid this.

I tried to explicitly load the base class through Mammal.find(cat.id), but it returned an instance of the inherited class Cat based on the type column automatically. I had hoped to get an instance of the Mammal class.

Comment: `current_user.last_pet.becomes(Mammal)` https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes

Comment: Ooohhh it also works the other way around! Somehow I assumed it only works for changing the base class to the derived class. Thanks a lot!

Comment: if you don't want a `Mammal` instance in the view, you can `redirect_to mammal_url(current_user.last_pet.id)` and pass in a cat as `@pet = current_user.last_pet` which will be an instance of `Cat`

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work, because it might return a reptile, fish or bird as well, who all don't have a mammal_url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to shoot yourself in the foot.  If you have a Dog and Cat class instead of just a Mammal class then they probably deserve their own controllers.  And if they behave the same then just make them trivial subclasses of a parent with shared behavior.

But if you really wanna do what you describe, I'd probably do it something like:

```
  def go_to_pet
    last_pet = current_user.last_pet
    if last_pet.class.superclass.abstract_class?
      redirect_to url_for(controller: last_pet.class.base_class.name.tableize, id; last_pet.id)
    else
      redirect_to current_user.last_pet || root_path
    end
  end
```

But mostly I'd probably just head it off in the routes.

```
  resources :dogs, controller: 'mammals'
```

Comment: Assigning the controller in routes.rb is exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update: After I wrote this answer the now accepted answer was posted, which is assigning the correct controller in routes.rb. This solves my problem in an even better way.

---

Alex wrote the correct answer in a comment to the question. It is:

```
becomes(Mammal)
```

[api.rubyonrails.org documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes)

I call it in the user model when retrieving the last pet like so:

```
if @pet.instance_of?(Cat) || @pet.instance_of?(Dog)
  @pet = @pet.becomes(Mammal)
end
```

So now I can redirect using `redirect_to current_user.last_pet || root_path` with confidence. Thanks again to Alex.

Comment: If you add more `Mammal`s this could get clunky. I am not sure if `Mammal` is abstract or not, but something like `@pet.becomes(@pet.class.base_class)` might work